# How to draw selectable text with QPainter?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qpainter

I need to implement a class like QGraphcisTextItem, however I need it to be selectable text.

However if my class descends from QGraphicsTextItem or QGraphicsItem, and I reimplement the paint event the ability for the text to be selectable is lost (I'm using drawText).

So my question is how can I create selectable text using QPainter's drawText?

Comment: You may draw a text background with different color where you want your selection to be. Color may be picked from QPalette.

Comment: Btw, your question sounds strange. Do you understand a difference between drawing and interaction with user? What is your exact problem? Did you do any research?

Comment: I do understand the difference. When you use a QGraphicsTextItem you can select the text and can then copy it. You have a specific function for this named setTextSelectable. It even enables a pop up menu for copying. I want that same functionality in a graphics text item that I want to implement myself. I can't use QGraphcisTextItem because I want my item to have different fonts. The only other way I can think of to accomplish this is to have multiple text items, but I don't think that is the way to go.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you can have multiple fonts if you use QGraphicsTextItem::setHtml(), and set the style (font) in the html

Comment: I thought about this as well, but the problem with this solution is that it is a font that I add to FontDatabse from a resource. I can't use a font added like that with html tags.

Comment: @aarelovich Are you sure about that? I think I've done it before and it "just worked", but I'd have to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue you have with custom fonts. That's a very important bit of information that belongs in the question and changes the question *substantially*.

The `addApplicationFont` is a static function that adds the font to the application-wide font database. Use the `applicationFontFamilies(int id)` to obtain the name of the family to use in html:

```
...
auto id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/myfont.ttf");
if (if == -1)
  return;
auto families = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id);
if (families.isEmpty())
  return;
auto face = families.first().toHtmlEscaped();
auto html = QStringLiteral("<font face=\"%1\">Hello</font>").arg(face);
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Once you told to try it straigth up I've tried it and it worked and forgot to check back. Thank you very much. I had no idea to to try it until I did what you showed here and it worked to my disbelief. I thought HTML tags had a very limited subset of fonts they could work with.